# People are complaining of low land value when surrounded by parks and services

Tags: cities-skylines

I have a city of about 5,000 residents in Cities Skylines, and a growing problem by the riverside is making people move out; low land value?!

I have parks and services aplenty in my city, but a neighborhood is complaining of low land value. This makes even less sense because the neighborhood in question is arguably the best in the city; lowest crime rate, most parks, services, etc...
And also, I have a *very* clean city, and there is no ground pollution for miles around the city.

I became quite intrigued in this troubled, spoiled neighborhood. As an experiment, I surrounded one of the affected houses with 2 Plazas, 2 Parks, and a fire station across the road. The problem not only didn't improve but got *worse*, and the house was abandoned. I added a custom park with no noise pollution instead of the plaza, with an even *higher* land value, and checked to see no type of pollution was reaching the other houses affected, and that house, as well as many others, were abandoned.

I haven't had a game update for months, haven't installed any new mods, and have been playing without issue for months. Can anyone help me? The city is losing its people. :(

Comment: Make sure you check all the coverages: fire, police, garbage, pollution, noise etc

Comment: @Tas As I said, surrounded by every service in town. My budget for these services is very high, and the city is really safe.

Comment: Presumably every service includes school, but what about jobs, public transport, noise?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a few screenshots?

Comment: What was the city population size? I found that game adorable until the city population reached 100,000 and then the whole city became one huge, whining, drag, with endless derelict buildings sprouting. Really felt as though there was an overpopulation unhappiness factor built in.

Comment: @Tas there is zero noise pollution in the area. Jobs are plentiful, and there's a huge transport network in the city.

Comment: @Bobulous the population is only 5,000.... And I haven't noticed this issue in the past.

Comment: 1) Does your riverside have quays? 2) Is your river maybe polluted, not land?